# How to Iterate a mongo cursor in reverse in python?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

How do you iterate through a pymongo cursor object in reverse? I tried using the reversed built-in but there was an error:

> TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

My code:

```
for document in reversed(cursor):
    documents.append(document)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cursor can't be reserved but I can specify in sort a negative value to return a cursor with values stored in reverse:

```
collection.find(query, {}).sort('some_field_to_sort_by' : -1)
```